# Can FFmpeg encode video in VP8 codec?

Tags: c, video, encoding, ffmpeg, vp8

Can FFmpeg encode video in VP8 codec? (I mean its trunk vercion)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Straight from the home page at [ffmpeg.org](http://www.ffmpeg.org/#release_0.6): the latest version (0.6) lists VP8 as supported via Google's libvpx library, for both encoding and decoding

Comment: The *ffvp8* encoder is much better than Google's libvpx http://x264dev.multimedia.cx/?p=499

Comment: @Cirno: but isn't in a formal ffmpeg release yet. When people say "trunk" I'm never sure whether they mean "head-of-trunk".

Comment: @Cimo: ffvp8 is for decoding only.

Comment: Guess I missed the 'd', *laff*.